# why do i get this IndentationError in my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I was developing a function in python. However I get this error IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

what should i do? Here is my code

```
def customerdetails():
      Firs_tname = input("Enter your First name:")
      Last_name = input("Enter your last name:")
      Age = input("Age:")
      Address =input("Enter your address:")
      Postcode = input("Enter your Postcode:")
      Email = input("Email:")
      Phone = int(input("Phone Number:"))
    customerdetails()
```

*I will use this function again and again*

Comment: You can see it in your code: The line `customerdetails()` has a different indentation. According to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should always use 4 spaces to indent.

Answer (score -2):

`customerdetails()` is inside the same function it's trying to call. You cannot call a function from inside itself this way. For this code to work `customerdetails()` must not be indented. Here is the correct code:

```py
def customerdetails():
      Firs_tname = input("Enter your First name:")
      Last_name = input("Enter your last name:")
      Age = input("Age:")
      Address =input("Enter your address:")
      Postcode = input("Enter your Postcode:")
      Email = input("Email:")
      Phone = int(input("Phone Number:"))
customerdetails()
```

Also, for indenting you should use tabs, as they are much more consistent than spaces (not everyone knows 4 spaces is the correct indentation), especially in an established text editor like VSC. Some people prefer spaces, but personally I feel they just make things unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: No. Spaces should be used for indentation. And a consistent number of them (preferably four)

Comment: If you use spaces you're more likely to mess up on indentation, and it's a lot slower to use than tabs. Again though, it's a matter of preference.

Comment: "You cannot call a function from inside itself"??? Have you ever heard of _recursion_? This might not apply here, but the statement as it is is wrong.

Comment: @Shidouuu - well. It's a matter of preference, and PEP8 - the official [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). You are free to use tabs, of course, but you shouldn't recommend this bad practice as "better". The main reason is that tab are in fact *not* consistent, across editors and OS-es.

Comment: PEP 8 was created in 2001. Modern text editors have no problem exchanging code with tabs.

Comment: @Matthias Sorry, you're right. What I meant to say is you cannot call a function from within itself using the traditional way.

Comment: PEP-8 was constantly revised and "use spaces instead of tabs" still stands. I every editor I know I can press the tab key and get as many spaces as I like, so it's not even faster.

Comment: The only reason why it hasn't been replaced with tabs is because spaces have *guaranteed* compatibility. However no one is going to use a 20 year-old text editor that faces tab compatibility issues. Find me a modern text-editor that has problems exchanging tabs, I'll wait.